# Getting AppID for Windows Phone in Unity3d

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I am developing game for windows phone in unity3d, I have inserted Rate me button in game but on run time in windows phone it didn't work, is there any method to access AppID for the current application running in windows phone developed in Unity3d. I need code in unity3d CSharp for getting AppID.

I tried this C# code in Unity but It didn't work and having error no keywork found windows.

```
 string appId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
 LinkUri = new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=" + appId, UriKind.Absolute)
```

Here I needed AppID to complete my link for rate me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know Unity can not access the Windows namespace but you can make use of EventHandler to call 'Review Task' from Unity. You can do this by following below steps(visit [Unity Expert](http://unityexpert.blogspot.com/2015/07/rate-review-button-for-windows-platform.html) for detailed explanation).

**In Unity Game Engine-**

Create Event -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

 public static class events
 {
         //Create a new event
         public static event EventHandler RateUs;

         public static void FireRateUs()
         {
                 Debug.Log ("Opening Rate Task......");
                 //If event is subscribed than fire it
                 if(RateUs!=null)
                         RateUs(null,null);
         } 
 }
```

Fire Event -

```
using UnityEngine;

 public class RateUs : MonoBehaviour 
 {
         void OnMouseDown()
         {
                 events.FireRateUs();
         }
 }
```

**In Visual Studio IDE**

Subscribe Event -

```
public MainPage()
 {
      .
      .
      .
      .
      events.RateUs += events_RateUs;
 }
```

Call Function -

```
void events_RateUs(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     String AppId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
     Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:reviewapp?appid=" + AppId));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your AppID from your developer's portal on Microsoft Create's web page. You can then hardcode it into your app or save it as a static/globally available variable for accessing purposes. This would mean you would have to begin the process of creating your app entry prior to the programming of the rating game feature. Just create the entry, and don't submit it! Or create it, and add Rate app as an update. I'd choose the former method, personally!

For Apple and Google rating/submit information you have to create the entry ahead of time to get a SKU number. Also in iTunes/Apple/iOS/OSX you have to create the app and give it a unique name, etc in the developer's portal/certificate store.